# how do perform aggregate functions to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:

```
df

Device  int   In   Out  Bw_in  Bw_out
Usa123  Eth1  1000  500   100   75
Usa123  Eth0  10000 700   200   80
Emea01  Wan1  1000  500   150   90
Emea01  Eth3  2000  1000  200   70
```

I want to summarize the Bandwidth usage data in terms of % usage per device, resulting data frame needs to look like this:

Need to sum BW_in per Dervice and divide it by sum of In per device.
Do the same for BW_out. Sum Bw_out per device divide it by sum of Out per divice

```
Device  int   In   Out  Bw_in  Bw_out %InUsage %OutUsage
Usa123  Eth1  1000  500   100   75    0.01     0.12
Usa123  Eth0  10000 700   200   80
Emea01  Wan1  1000  500   150   90    0.11     0.10
Emea01  Eth3  2000  1000  200   70
```

I tried this:

```
df.groupby('Device'. apply(lambda x: sum(x['Bw_in'])/sum(x['In']))
```

I am trying to see if there is a better and more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do the operation in "bulk", without `.apply`:

```py
g = df.groupby("Device")

df[["%InUsage", "%OutUsage"]] = (
    g[["Bw_in", "Bw_out"]].transform("sum")
    / g[["In", "Out"]].transform("sum").to_numpy()
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Device   int     In   Out  Bw_in  Bw_out  %InUsage  %OutUsage
0  Usa123  Eth1   1000   500    100      75  0.027273   0.129167
1  Usa123  Eth0  10000   700    200      80  0.027273   0.129167
2  Emea01  Wan1   1000   500    150      90  0.116667   0.106667
3  Emea01  Eth3   2000  1000    200      70  0.116667   0.106667
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# sum per group
tmp = df.groupby('Device', sort=False)[['In', 'Out', 'Bw_in', 'Bw_out']].sum()

# identify first row of each group
m = ~df['Device'].duplicated()

# assign the ratio
df.loc[m, ['%InUsage', '%OutUsage']] = (tmp[['Bw_in', 'Bw_out']].to_numpy()
                                       /tmp[['In', 'Out']].to_numpy())
```

Output:

```
   Device   int     In   Out  Bw_in  Bw_out  %InUsage  %OutUsage
0  Usa123  Eth1   1000   500    100      75  0.027273   0.129167
1  Usa123  Eth0  10000   700    200      80       NaN        NaN
2  Emea01  Wan1   1000   500    150      90  0.116667   0.106667
3  Emea01  Eth3   2000  1000    200      70       NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

In case the dataframe is large and speed is needed, [`duckdb`](https://duckdb.org/) can be used to fastly produce the result in a pandas dataframe:

```
import duckdb

conn = duckdb.connect(database=':memory:', read_only=False)
conn.register('df_table', df)

query = """
SELECT 
    Device, 
    SUM(Bw_in) / SUM(\"In\") AS \"%InUsage\", 
    SUM(Bw_out) / SUM(\"Out\") AS \"%OutUsage\"
FROM df_table
GROUP BY Device
"""

conn.execute(query).fetchdf() # the results are returned as a pandas dataframe
```

Output:

```
   Device  %InUsage  %OutUsage
0  Usa123  0.027273   0.129167
1  Emea01  0.116667   0.106667
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to chunk it in steps, with a lazy groupby and `assign` - it is a variation of Andrej Kesely's solution, without having to convert to numpy:

```py
grp = df.drop(columns='int').groupby('Device').transform('sum')
grp = {"%InUsage" : grp['Bw_in'] / grp['In'], 
       "%OutUsage" : grp['Bw_out'] / grp['Out']}
df.assign(**grp)

   Device   int     In   Out  Bw_in  Bw_out  %InUsage  %OutUsage
0  Usa123  Eth1   1000   500    100      75  0.027273   0.129167
1  Usa123  Eth0  10000   700    200      80  0.027273   0.129167
2  Emea01  Wan1   1000   500    150      90  0.116667   0.106667
3  Emea01  Eth3   2000  1000    200      70  0.116667   0.106667
```